# Automatically calculating value (point feature) between contour line (drawn by user) using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, contour

I want to extract the value of a point from the contour line, which is shown in the below picture.

Let me clarify a bit. I don't have the source raster or lidar. The contour line is basically drawn by me to represent the magnitude of sth and the point is the location of somewhere. My thought is to determine the magnitude of that location from the contour line in GIS (maybe through scripting? Not sure if there is a smarter way).

And more importantly, my final goal is to automate this process and integrate it with other datasets.

How do I do this using ArcMap?

[image]

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  What have you tried?

Comment: Extracting the value from the line wouldn't be of much use unless you get the high and low values from both lines or the high and low from the polygon to begin interpolation. Far more details from an actual attempt are necessary.

Comment: I actually have no idea how to do it, I am wondering if I can extract the value which is not on the contour line in ArcMap.

Comment: Hi Vince, or is there a tool to analyze which is the closer contour line from the point?

Comment: Hello @HCChan, Welcome to the community, the drawing explanation is really great! May I know what is base data you will be using or have to create a contour? For example a raster surface (DEM). And if you just want to view the value of a contour at any specific location created using a raster using the "Identify Tool" and the related pixel value shall give you the exact value. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcreader/identifying-features-by-pointing-at-them.htm

Comment: Hi @YogeshChavan, thanks! Basically, the contour line and its represented intensity will be drawn and determined by me. My thought is to determine the magnitude of that point from the contour line in GIS (maybe through scripting? Not sure if there is a smarter way).

Comment: The smarter way is automate your procedure of drawing contour line.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks, etc in your posts. If you wish to apply an ArcPy tag the please include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a raster surface model data like DTM or DEM, you can use Raster To Point tool. Basically, it converts a raster dataset to point features for each cell of the input raster dataset. The points will be positioned at the centers of cells that they represent. This tool is available in both ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro.
Link: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-point.htm

Comment: Hi, what if the contour line is not from DTM/ DEM. My thought is the contour line will be drawn to represent the intensity of sth, and the point is the location of somewhere. And I want to determine the intensity of that location from the contour line.

Comment: @Hc Chan you can apply this procedure -->  1. Find the point you want to know the height of.
2. Find the elevations of the contour lines on each side of it.
3. Estimate the height of the point between those elevations.
 Ex: i. if a point is 1/4 of the way between the 250 m and 300 m contours, we estimate its height as 250 plus 1/4 of the contour interval (in this case 50 m).
ii.  250 + 50/4 or 262.5 m.
Note: this is an estimate only, don't suggest you know it to within 0.5 m; round to the nearest 10 m, and call it 260 m

Comment: That is what am I thinking, my follow-up question is if there is any tool to extract the "height value" from both sides of the contour line in GIS so that I can apply the process for estimation?

Comment: You can use the identity (i) tool on ArcGIS

Comment: I would like to automate the calculation process but it seems that the identify tool is not able to extract the value for this purpose?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. You will need a raster representing your topo and a feature class with your point/points. Then, run the Extract Values to Point or Extract Multivalues to Points tool. https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/analytics/analytics/how-to-extract-raster-values-at-point-locations/

If you have the source raster or lidar used to create the contours, definitely use that. Otherwise you can run the Topo to Raster tool using your contours, but generally this is bad practice since contours are already an interpolated measurement of a surface.

Comment: Yes I don't have the source raster or lidar. The contour line is basically drawn by myself to represent the magnitude of sth and the point is the location of somewhere. My thought is to determine the intensity of that location from the contour line in GIS.

Comment: In that case run the Topo to Raster > Then extract values to Points. Topo to Raster will produce a Raster with the values interpolated between your contour lines.